Nanny kills mother of the house in a bathtub
All I can seem to remember from this film (pretty sure it was a tv movie) is the scene where the nanny is confronting the mother of the house in the bathtub. While they talk to each other the nanny informs her that she's in fact her biological daughter. In a fit of rage the nanny throws a radio inside the bathtub causing her mother to get electrified to death.
Anybody knows what is the title of this feature?

When did you see it?  Was it in English?  Can you remember where it was set?  Are you sure about this scene?  What did the actors look like?  Anyone famous?

Might it be the 2007 Lifetime movie The Sitter a.k.a. While the Children Sleep? The basic plot of that film revolves around a homicidal babysitter. There is a scene where the sitter electrocutes a lady in a bathtub using a stereo (scene available on YouTube here).
